# ZFS send single snapshot including descendent file systems

Tags: zfs

Is there a way to send a single snapshot including descendant file systems?  'zfs send' only sends the the top level file system even if the snapshot was created using '-r'.  'zfs send -R' sends the descendant file systems but includes all the previous snapshots, which for disaster recovery purposes consumes unnecessary space if the previous snapshots are not needed in the disaster recovery pool.

cat /sys/module/zfs/version
0.8.3-1ubuntu12.5

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I perfectly understand your use case. Although I for one am usually faced with the oppositie situation where I have a remote backup pool from which I want to restore the latest snapshot on a local system.

In any case, while you cannot achieve what you want in a direct way, you can reach the desired state. The idea is to prune your recovery set so that it only has the latest snapshot.
You start by sending an initial snapshot:

```
host# zfs snapshot -r tank/data@initial_snapshot
host# zfs send -R tank/data@initial_snapshot | \
 ssh recovery-host zfs recv tank/data
```

This will send all descending file systems, and will send the `initial_snapshot` and all those created before it.
If you thus had created any snapshots prior, you can delete them:

```
recovery-host# zfs list -H -o name -t snapshot tank/data | head -n -1 \
 | xargs -r -n 1 zfs destroy -r -v
```

Then you send incremental updates and prune,

```
host# zfs snapshot -r tank/data@${LATEST_LOCAL_SNAPSHOT}
host# zfs send -R -i tank/data@${LATEST_REMOTE_SNAPSHOT} \
 tank/data@${LATEST_LOCAL_SNAPSHOT} | ssh recovery-host zfs recv tank/data
recovery-host# zfs list -H -o name -t snapshot tank/data | head -n -1 \
 | xargs -r -n 1 zfs destroy -r -v
```

assuming that `LATEST_LOCAL_SNAPSHOT` and `LATEST_REMOTE_SNAPSHOT`  are appropriately set.

Please mind that this is a minimal seatbelt-less example. You should care about whether your send-receives are successful. If accidently reach the state where your recovery pool does not have any snapshots that match your source, you can no longer send increments and will thus need to start anew.

Comment: Thank you.  This is pretty much what I've reverted to for the time being.  My other thought is to script sending the snapshot and its descendants but I was hoping that ZFS had this feature natively.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you want the entire filesystem for disaster recovery, you need the entire filesystem.

A ZFS snapshot is not a complete filesystem.  It's effectively the difference between it and the previous snapshot, and that chain continues all the way back through all the snapshots to the "base" copy of the filesystem.

You can send incremental snapshots, which only send the differences.  Per [Oracle ZFS documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbchx/index.html):

> ...
>
> If you are sending the snapshot stream to a different system, pipe the
> zfs send output through the ssh command. For example:
>
> ```
> host1# zfs send tank/dana@snap1 | ssh host2 zfs recv newtank/dana
> ```
>
> When you send a full stream, the destination file system must not
> exist.
>
> You can send incremental data by using the zfs send -i option. For
> example:
>
> ```
> host1# zfs send -i tank/dana@snap1 tank/dana@snap2 | ssh host2 zfs recv newtank/dana
> ```
>
> Note that the first argument (snap1) is the earlier snapshot and the
> second argument (snap2) is the later snapshot. In this case, the
> newtank/dana file system must already exist for the incremental
> receive to be successful.

The first `zfs` command

```
host1# zfs send tank/dana@snap1 | ssh host2 zfs recv newtank/dana
```

Sends the entire filesystem.

This one just sends the differences:

```
host1# zfs send -i tank/dana@snap1 tank/dana@snap2 | ssh host2 zfs recv newtank/dana
```

Which can then be followed by

```
host1# zfs send -i tank/dana@snap2 tank/dana@snap3 | ssh host2 zfs recv newtank/dana
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it does not appear to be correct.  'send' without -R does not send the decedent filesystems.  Also, a zfs snapshot is a complete filesystem and not just the incremental difference between 2 snapshots.  Multiple references mention the same including the Oracle documentation, "A snapshot is a read-only copy of a file system or volume."  See also, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXg86uBDSqI for detail.

If I'm mistaken, please advise on where it references that "a snapshot is the difference between it and the previous snapshot..."  I did not see the same.

Comment: @alpha23 Add the `-R`...

Comment: My original question was is there a way to send  a single snapshot including descendant file systems [without using -R because -R includes all the previous snapshots, etc.]?

Comment: @alpha23 And the answer remains:  **NO**.  Sending a single snapshot makes no sense.  If you want to replicate your data, you use the `zfs send -R ...`.   You seem to have failed to realize that you don't have to send the entire filesystem each time, which is why I mentioned sending incremental snapshots.  You seem to have fixated on doing something that's not possible while ignoring a solution that will run a lot faster and use a lot less bandwidth.

Comment: You are reiterating the documentation, which I had already read and which does not offer a solution to my original post.  Moreover, my post is unrelated to incremental snapshots because incremental snapshots are not applicable to my question.

For reference, there is an alternative solution which involves scripting; I was looking for a solution in which ZFS handles this natively.   I encourage you to watch the video above to understand how ZFS snapshots work as your statement regarding sending a single snapshot is incorrect.

Comment: @alpha23 *my post is unrelated to incremental snapshots because incremental snapshots are not applicable to my question*  - you *CAN'T* replicate an entire filesystem including descendants without dealing will all the prior snapshots, and the solution to not having to send all that data every time is **incremental snapshots**.